# What determines the order of UI decorators in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have two string decorators (org.eclipse.ui.decorators extension), both of them are suffixes and I want them to be displayed in a specific order.

I.e. a package should be displayed in the navigator like this:

```
com.mycorp.mypackage - [READONLY][mysource.xml]
```

And not so:

```
com.mycorp.mypackage - [mysource.xml][READONLY]
```

How can I define their order? Moving them up and down in the Extensions list did not help.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to control this order.

Comment: But interestingly it's consequent between launches, so it must be something with the way I name the classes implementing the extension. Could this be right?

Comment: I think the values are stored in a HashMap so the order is likely to be iteration order of the map which will be based on the hash code of the key. This will be consistent but difficult to predict.